# how customize the texture and materials of the building generated by `Buildify` from the OSM building data

Tags: blender-osm

I have generated a building, from an Open Street map using `Blosm for Blender`.

Additionally, I have also used Buildify 1.0 to generate the building textures and architecture.

And as an output, I have got the following building.

[image]

In the same way, I have to export the other various buildings, the textures generated from `Buildify` are similar for all the buildings, So I would like to try out the different textures and materials for some buildings.

I have to use the building structure from the OSM building data.

But with very limited knowledge about the Blender, I am not able to head start with changing the textures, and building materials.

To generate the building I have followed the following tutorials. https://youtu.be/gKZ074ISG_M?t=354

My question is how to start with changing the texture and materials of the building generated by `Buildify` from the OSM building data.

I have attached the blender files too.

[image]

Comment: Since Buildify appears to be a paid-for third-party addon, questions about it are really off-topic here.

Comment: sorry. It is not a paid version, it can be used in blender-osm, without pay.

Comment: It is still a third-party addon and not built into Blender. Just looking at one of the materials in the file, it appears to be created with a series of quite complex Geometry node groups so that's not something which we can help with anyway.